# How to enable multi valued profile fields in contribution page?

Tags: profile, multi-record

I have included a profile in a contribution page,
I need to add multiple combination of first name,last name and email value in the contribution in a way that I have an Add More Button which can load combination of fields if required
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create custom fields against contact and include them in a profile and using JS play hide and seek with those custom fields or you can create your own fields using buildform hooks and add it to profile form and include JS to hide show.

HTH

Pradeep